# Find all possible positive semi definite integers whose weighted sum is equal certain integer

Tags: fortran, integer-arithmetic

I am having problem with fortran 90 code. So, I have `n+1` positive semi definite integers `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, ... , `kn` and `n`. Now for a given `n`, I need to find all possible combinations of `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, ... , `kn` such that `k1+2*k2+3*k3+...+n*kn = n`. One might think of using a n-level nested loops, each for `ki` where it runs from `0` to `n` but actually I will put this code in a subroutine and `n` (that is, the number of `k`'s) will be an input to this subroutine. Therefore if I were to use a nested loops, then the number of nesting levels should be automated which I believe is difficult (if not impossible) to do with Fortran. Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: It can also be formulated that way, but the main problem is to have Fortran find all possible combinations of `ki`'s which satisfy the above requirement.

Comment: This is either trolling or homework. If not, can you explain what you are trying to do and why?

Comment: This is neither trolling nor homework. I am actually trying to compute the derivative of arbitrary order of a function f(g(x)) with respect to x using the so called Faa di Bruno formula. If you look at equation (1) in [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html) you will understand why I need to do what I explained in my post.

Comment: But why - not what? Anyhow, look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming which is probably the right approach if you are serious.

Comment: For my research.

Comment: in the [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html), the condition is that `k1 + 2*k2 + ... +n*kn = n` not `<=n`. Why did you modify the condition?.

Comment: My mistake, you are right it should be equal sign only. But I guess it doesn't change the problem too much, does it.

Comment: Perhaps if the subroutine were recursive, you could do recursive calls as needed, essentially changing the depth of nesting dynamically.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark This is not `k1+k2+k3..=n`, it is `k1+2*k2+3*k3+...n*kn=n` So there is no permutations. Example for `n=2`: The possible values are {2,0} {0,1} . {0,2} ( 0+2*2 /=2) and {1,0} (1+2*0/=2) are not solutions.

Comment: Yeah I have been thinking of using recursive function (or subroutine if it's applicable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n` is rather small (say, 5), I think it is simpler to write multi-dimensional loops to obtain desired k-vectors (k1,k2,...,kn) that satisfy k1 + k2*2 + ... + kn*n = n. Otherwise, it may be an option to use recursion. An example code may look like this (note that we need `recursive` keyword):

```
module recur_mod
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: nvecmax = 1000
contains

subroutine recur_main( n, kveclist, nvec )
    integer, intent(in)               :: n
    integer, allocatable, intent(out) :: kveclist(:,:)  !! list of k-vectors
    integer, intent(out)              :: nvec           !! number of k-vectors
    integer kvec( n ), ind

    allocate( kveclist( n, nvecmax ) )
    kveclist(:,:) = 0
    nvec = 0
    ind = 1
    kvec(:) = 0
    call recur_sub( n, ind, kvec, kveclist, nvec )  !! now entering recursion...

endsubroutine 

recursive subroutine recur_sub( n, ind, kvec, kveclist, nvec )
    integer, intent(in)    :: n, ind
    integer, intent(inout) :: kvec(:), kveclist(:,:), nvec
    integer  k, ksum, t, ind_next

    do k = 0, n
        kvec( ind ) = k

        ksum = sum( [( kvec( t ) * t, t = 1, ind )] )  !! k1 + k2*2 + ... + ki*i
        if ( ksum > n ) cycle                          !! early rejection

        if ( ind < n ) then
            ind_next = ind + 1  
            call recur_sub( n, ind_next, kvec, kveclist, nvec )  !! go to the next index
        endif
        if ( ind == n .and. ksum == n ) then
            nvec = nvec + 1
            if ( nvec > nvecmax ) stop "nvecmax too small"
            kveclist( :, nvec ) = kvec(:)                     !! save k-vectors
        endif
    enddo

endsubroutine

end

program main
    use recur_mod
    implicit none
    integer, allocatable :: kveclist(:,:)
    integer :: n, nvec, ivec

    do n = 1, 4
        call recur_main( n, kveclist, nvec )

        print *
        print *, "For n = ", n
        do ivec = 1, nvec
            print *, "kvec = ", kveclist( :, ivec )
        enddo
    enddo
end
```

which gives (with gfortran 7.1)

```
 For n = 1
 kvec =            1

 For n = 2
 kvec =            0           1
 kvec =            2           0

 For n = 3
 kvec =            0           0           1
 kvec =            1           1           0
 kvec =            3           0           0

 For n = 4
 kvec =            0           0           0           1
 kvec =            0           2           0           0
 kvec =            1           0           1           0
 kvec =            2           1           0           0
 kvec =            4           0           0           0
```

Here, we can see that, for example, `kvec = [k1,k2,k3,k4] = [2,1,0,0]` for n=4 satisfies `k1 + k2*2 + k3*3 + k4*4 = 2 + 1*2 + 0 + 0 = 4`. Using these k-vectors, we can evaluate the n-th derivative of f(g(x)) (as mentioned by OP, following this [page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html)).

---

To see how the recursion works, it is often useful to insert a lot
of `print` statements and monitor how the variables change. For example, a "verbose" version of the code may look like this (here, I have deleted early rejection things for simplicity):

```
recursive subroutine recur_sub( n, ind, kvec, kveclist, nvec )
    integer, intent(in)    :: n, ind
    integer, intent(inout) :: kvec(:), kveclist(:,:), nvec
    integer  k, ksum, t, ind_next

    print *, "Top of recur_sub: ind = ", ind

    do k = 0, n

        kvec( ind ) = k
        print *, "ind = ", ind, " k = ", k, "kvec = ", kvec

        if ( ind < n ) then
            ind_next = ind + 1
            print *, "  > now going to the next level"
            call recur_sub( n, ind_next, kvec, kveclist, nvec )
            print *, "  > returned to the current level"
        endif
        if ( ind == n ) then
            ksum = sum( [( kvec( t ) * t, t = 1, n )] )

            if ( ksum == n ) then
                nvec = nvec + 1
                if ( nvec > nvecmax ) stop "nvecmax too small"
                kveclist( :, nvec ) = kvec(:)
            endif
        endif
    enddo

    print *, "Exiting recur_sub"
endsubroutine
```

which gives for `n = 2`:

```
 Top of recur_sub: ind =            1
 ind =            1  k =            0 kvec =            0           0
   > now going to the next level
 Top of recur_sub: ind =            2
 ind =            2  k =            0 kvec =            0           0
 ind =            2  k =            1 kvec =            0           1
 ind =            2  k =            2 kvec =            0           2
 Exiting recur_sub
   > returned to the current level
 ind =            1  k =            1 kvec =            1           2
   > now going to the next level
 Top of recur_sub: ind =            2
 ind =            2  k =            0 kvec =            1           0
 ind =            2  k =            1 kvec =            1           1
 ind =            2  k =            2 kvec =            1           2
 Exiting recur_sub
   > returned to the current level
 ind =            1  k =            2 kvec =            2           2
   > now going to the next level
 Top of recur_sub: ind =            2
 ind =            2  k =            0 kvec =            2           0
 ind =            2  k =            1 kvec =            2           1
 ind =            2  k =            2 kvec =            2           2
 Exiting recur_sub
   > returned to the current level
 Exiting recur_sub

 For n =            2
 kvec =            0           1
 kvec =            2           0
```

Please note that the values of arrays `kvec` and `kveclist` are always retained upon entry and exit of recursive calls. In particular, we are overwriting the elements of `kvec` for each dimension to obtain a full list of possible patterns (so essentially equivalent to multi-dimensional loops). We also note that the values of `kvec` are significant only at the final recursion level (i.e., `ind = n`).

---

Another approach to get the working is to rewrite the recursive call to equivalent, non-recursive ones for specific `n`. For example, the case of `n = 2` may be rewritten as follows. This does not rely on recursion but performs the same operation as the above code (for `n = 2`). If we imagine inlining `recur_sub2` into `recur_sub`, it becomes clear that those routines are equivalent to 2-dimensional loops over `k1` and `k2`.

```
!! routine specific for n = 2
subroutine recur_sub( n, ind, kvec, kveclist, nvec )
    integer, intent(in)    :: n, ind
    integer, intent(inout) :: kvec(:), kveclist(:,:), nvec
    integer  k1

    !! now ind == 1

    do k1 = 0, n
        kvec( ind ) = k1

        call recur_sub2( n, ind + 1, kvec, kveclist, nvec )  !! go to next index
    enddo

endsubroutine

!! routine specific for n = 2
subroutine recur_sub2( n, ind, kvec, kveclist, nvec )
    integer, intent(in)    :: n, ind
    integer, intent(inout) :: kvec(:), kveclist(:,:), nvec
    integer  k2, ksum, t

    !! now ind == n == 2

    do k2 = 0, n
        kvec( ind ) = k2

        ksum = sum( [( kvec( t ) * t, t = 1, n )] )

        if ( ksum == 2 ) then
            nvec = nvec + 1
            if ( nvec > nvecmax ) stop "nvecmax too small"
            kveclist( :, nvec ) = kvec(:)    !! save k-vectors
        endif
    enddo

endsubroutine
```

---

Appendix

The following is a "pretty print" routine (in Julia) for the n-th derivative of f(g(x)) (just for fun). If necessary, please make the corresponding routine in Fortran (but please be careful about large n!)

```
function recur_main( n )

    kvec = zeros( Int, n )       # [k1,k2,...,kn] (work vector)
    kveclist = Vector{Int}[]     # list of k-vectors (output)

    recur_sub( n, 1, kvec, kveclist )   # now entering recursion over {ki}...

    return kveclist
end

function recur_sub( n, i, kvec, kveclist )

    for ki = 0 : n
        kvec[ i ] = ki

        ksum = sum( kvec[ t ] * t for t = 1:i )  # k1 + k2*2 + ... + ki*i
        ksum > n && continue                     # early rejection

        if i < n
            recur_sub( n, i + 1, kvec, kveclist )   # go to the next index
        end
        if i == n && ksum == n
            push!( kveclist, copy( kvec ) )   # save k-vectors
        end
    end
end

function showderiv( n )

    kveclist = recur_main( n )

    println()
    println( "(f(g))_$(n) = " )

    fact( k ) = factorial( big(k) )

    for (term, kvec) in enumerate( kveclist )

        fac1 = div( fact( n ), prod( fact( kvec[ i ] ) for i = 1:n ) )
        fac2 = prod( fact( i )^kvec[ i ] for i = 1:n )
        coeff = div( fac1, fac2 )

        term  == 1 ? print( "   " )    : print( " + " )
        coeff == 1 ? print( " " ^ 15 ) : @printf( "%15i", coeff )  
        print( " (f$( sum( kvec ) ))" )

        for i = 1 : length( kvec )
            ki = kvec[ i ]
            if ki > 0
                print( "(g$( i ))" )
                ki > 1 && print( "^$( ki )" )
            end
        end
        println()
    end
end

#--- test ---
if false
for n = 1 : 4
    kveclist = recur_main( n )

    println( "\nFor n = ", n )
    for kvec in kveclist
        println( "kvec = ", kvec )
    end
end
end

showderiv( 1 )
showderiv( 2 )
showderiv( 3 )
showderiv( 4 )
showderiv( 5 )
showderiv( 8 )
showderiv( 10 )
```

Result (where `fm` and `gm` mean the m-th derivative of `f` and `g`, respectively):

```
(f(g))_1 = 
                   (f1)(g1)

(f(g))_2 = 
                   (f1)(g2)
 +                 (f2)(g1)^2

(f(g))_3 = 
                   (f1)(g3)
 +               3 (f2)(g1)(g2)
 +                 (f3)(g1)^3

(f(g))_4 = 
                   (f1)(g4)
 +               3 (f2)(g2)^2
 +               4 (f2)(g1)(g3)
 +               6 (f3)(g1)^2(g2)
 +                 (f4)(g1)^4

(f(g))_5 = 
                   (f1)(g5)
 +              10 (f2)(g2)(g3)
 +               5 (f2)(g1)(g4)
 +              15 (f3)(g1)(g2)^2
 +              10 (f3)(g1)^2(g3)
 +              10 (f4)(g1)^3(g2)
 +                 (f5)(g1)^5

(f(g))_8 = 
                   (f1)(g8)
 +              35 (f2)(g4)^2
 +              56 (f2)(g3)(g5)
 +              28 (f2)(g2)(g6)
 +             280 (f3)(g2)(g3)^2
 +             210 (f3)(g2)^2(g4)
 +             105 (f4)(g2)^4
 +               8 (f2)(g1)(g7)
 +             280 (f3)(g1)(g3)(g4)
 +             168 (f3)(g1)(g2)(g5)
 +             840 (f4)(g1)(g2)^2(g3)
 +              28 (f3)(g1)^2(g6)
 +             280 (f4)(g1)^2(g3)^2
 +             420 (f4)(g1)^2(g2)(g4)
 +             420 (f5)(g1)^2(g2)^3
 +              56 (f4)(g1)^3(g5)
 +             560 (f5)(g1)^3(g2)(g3)
 +              70 (f5)(g1)^4(g4)
 +             210 (f6)(g1)^4(g2)^2
 +              56 (f6)(g1)^5(g3)
 +              28 (f7)(g1)^6(g2)
 +                 (f8)(g1)^8

(f(g))_10 = 
                   (f1)(g10)
 +             126 (f2)(g5)^2
 +             210 (f2)(g4)(g6)
 +             120 (f2)(g3)(g7)
 +            2100 (f3)(g3)^2(g4)
 +              45 (f2)(g2)(g8)
 +            1575 (f3)(g2)(g4)^2
 +            2520 (f3)(g2)(g3)(g5)
 +             630 (f3)(g2)^2(g6)
 +            6300 (f4)(g2)^2(g3)^2
 +            3150 (f4)(g2)^3(g4)
 +             945 (f5)(g2)^5
 +              10 (f2)(g1)(g9)
 +            1260 (f3)(g1)(g4)(g5)
 +             840 (f3)(g1)(g3)(g6)
 +            2800 (f4)(g1)(g3)^3
 +             360 (f3)(g1)(g2)(g7)
 +           12600 (f4)(g1)(g2)(g3)(g4)
 +            3780 (f4)(g1)(g2)^2(g5)
 +           12600 (f5)(g1)(g2)^3(g3)
 +              45 (f3)(g1)^2(g8)
 +            1575 (f4)(g1)^2(g4)^2
 +            2520 (f4)(g1)^2(g3)(g5)
 +            1260 (f4)(g1)^2(g2)(g6)
 +           12600 (f5)(g1)^2(g2)(g3)^2
 +            9450 (f5)(g1)^2(g2)^2(g4)
 +            4725 (f6)(g1)^2(g2)^4
 +             120 (f4)(g1)^3(g7)
 +            4200 (f5)(g1)^3(g3)(g4)
 +            2520 (f5)(g1)^3(g2)(g5)
 +           12600 (f6)(g1)^3(g2)^2(g3)
 +             210 (f5)(g1)^4(g6)
 +            2100 (f6)(g1)^4(g3)^2
 +            3150 (f6)(g1)^4(g2)(g4)
 +            3150 (f7)(g1)^4(g2)^3
 +             252 (f6)(g1)^5(g5)
 +            2520 (f7)(g1)^5(g2)(g3)
 +             210 (f7)(g1)^6(g4)
 +             630 (f8)(g1)^6(g2)^2
 +             120 (f8)(g1)^7(g3)
 +              45 (f9)(g1)^8(g2)
 +                 (f10)(g1)^10
```

Comment: I think you should stick with Fortran Since the question is about a Fortran program.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works just as I have planned in mind but you save me a big time.

Comment: Now arranged the answer so that Fortran comes directly. hope this is clear enough...

Comment: Hi, I have a question about the working of your Fortran code. Let's assume n=2. At first you got `kvec=[0,0]`, at this point of the iteration cycle `i=2` am I right? The code finds that this is not a solution hence it needs to cycle over the first "slot" in `kvec` such that `kvec(1)=1` but how do you make `i` goes back to `1`?

Comment: The code starts from `i=1`, because I first call `recur_sub( n, 1, kvec, kveclist, nvec )`. Then, this routine calls itself with `i` increased by 1, such that call `recur_sub( n, i + 1, kvec, kveclist, nvec )`. That is, the code proceeds as `i = 1 -> 2 -> ... -> n`, and fills the element of `kvec` in the direction `k1 -> k2 -> ... -> kn`. Once `i = n`, we obtain one instance of fully filled `kvec` and judge whether it satisfies the desired condition. (The "early rejection" thing is just for efficiency, and we could calculate sum(k1+k2*2+...) only at the last step, if desired.)

Comment: Let me briefly explain what I understand, if there is any mistake it might be caused by my lack understanding of the recursive subroutine. So, let's say n=2 and in the `recur_sub` the call level already reaches the last one where it won't encounter itself again, at this moment `i=n=2`. Then upon going on the code to reach the end of the `recur_sub` the compiler will basically return to the previous invocation where `i=1`. So the variable `i` goes back to its previous value but `kvec`, `nvec`, and `kveclist` retain their last value because they are declared as the outputs of the subroutine?

Comment: @nougako Hi, I tried updating the answer for more clarification. And yes, the values of `kvec`, `nvec`, and `kveclist` are retained both upon entry and exit of recursive calls, because they are passed by reference (default in Fortran) and also `intent(inout)` is attached (which tells the compiler to retain any values).